# IntelliJ launches internet explorer in no addons mode which disables my gwt plugin

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, intellij-idea, internet-explorer-10

I'm developing a GWT application and I hate using super dev mode so I've still been using IE as it still supports NPAPI plugins. The problem is that when I have IntelliJ launch the browser as part of the run configuration, it opens it in IE (No Addons) mode which then disables the GWT plugin.

Now, I can take the URL and open normal IE and paste it in which works fine, however it's horribly annoying that I can't just have it launch without the extra work.

So far, in IntelliJ where you can setup the browsers, I've pointed the IE one to a shortcut that I know launches in normal IE, yet it still somehow opens in no addons mode when IntelliJ launches it.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Edit: I know other people who have used IE while developing a GWT app in IntelliJ and they never ran into this issue, so it's possible it's an IE issue and not necessarily IntelliJ related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I had to clear the oophm.dll file and download the installer directly. From there, I needed to run the following command from the command prompt with administrator priveleges:

regsvr32.exe "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Google Web Toolkit\Developer Plugin\IE\oophm.dll"

Answer (score 1):

When setting up the browser are you setting the path to the IE executable or a shortcut to a website ("launches in normal IE" doesnt make this clear).

Under tools > web browsers, for Internet Explorer is the path iexplore?

If you go to Run, via the start menu and enter what is in the path box in IntelliJ, does the correct IE start?

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response!
Secondly, I have it pointed to the executable at C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
If I run that from the start menu or by navigating directly to it and launching it, IE opens in the normal mode (i.e I can paste the dev mode URL into the browser and it'll load fine). But when IntelliJ launches IE from that same exact executable the plugin fails to load

Comment: When you launch IntelliJ, can you run it as administrator? Shift right click on the desktop shortcut to IntelliJ then select run as administrator for example.

Comment: There may be a guard then by Windows or your antivirus to stop other processes launching iexplore.exe running addons from a security point of view.

Comment: Could be. I'll poke around and see if I can find anything. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's antivirus related. Any other ideas?